# Python3 Subprocess Exited with Error (pyproject.toml)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, compiler-errors, subprocess

I'm installing this package https://github.com/fuzailpalnak/kaizen, with this command:

```
pip3 install kaizen-mapping
```

but I'm getting this error. I've looked up online from many sites have a similar error, which seems to suggest that the root of the error is likely in the python version or in pip. Anyone knows how I can resolve this issue? Thanks!

```
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [45 lines of output]
      Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
      AssertionError:
      Running from numpy source directory.
      <string>:470: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
      AssertionError:
      Processing numpy/random/_bounded_integers.pxd.in
      Processing numpy/random/_philox.pyx
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/private/var/folders/3g/6bwtmr4x4m3dvzm2dwby16q40000gn/T/pip-install-m94k6wqb/numpy/tools/cythonize.py", line 59, in process_pyx
          from Cython.Compiler.Version import version as cython_version
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
      
      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
      
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/private/var/folders/3g/6bwtmr4x4m3dvzm2dwby16q40000gn/T/pip-install-m94k6wqb/numpy/tools/cythonize.py", line 235, in <module>
          main()
        File "/private/var/folders/3g/6bwtmr4x4m3dvzm2dwby16q40000gn/T/pip-install-m94k6wqb/numpy/tools/cythonize.py", line 231, in main
          find_process_files(root_dir)
        File "/private/var/folders/3g/6bwtmr4x4m3dvzm2dwby16q40000gn/T/pip-install-m94k6wqb/numpy/tools/cythonize.py", line 222, in find_process_files
          process(root_dir, fromfile, tofile, function, hash_db)
        File "/private/var/folders/3g/6bwtmr4x4m3dvzm2dwby16q40000gn/T/pip-install-m94k6wqb/numpy/tools/cythonize.py", line 188, in process
          processor_function(fromfile, tofile)
        File "/private/var/folders/3g/6bwtmr4x4m3dvzm2dwby16q40000gn/T/pip-install-m94k6wqb/numpy/tools/cythonize.py", line 64, in process_pyx
          raise OSError('Cython needs to be installed in Python as a module')
      OSError: Cython needs to be installed in Python as a module
      Cythonizing sources
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 164, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
        File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 188, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          self.run_setup()
        File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 281, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 174, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 499, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 479, in setup_package
        File "<string>", line 274, in generate_cython
      RuntimeError: Running cythonize failed!
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> numpy

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

P.S. Another thing I tried was installing it with this as I saw it from another Stackoverflow site that this is how they resolved it but the same error:

```
pip3 install kaizen-mapping --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver
```

Answer (score 1):

You has not installed `Cython` -- This is clearly written in there:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
OSError: Cython needs to be installed in Python as a module
```

You can try `pip install cython` and try it again.